# Uso corretto di usare e utilizzare

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I verbi *usare* e *utilizzare* sono spesso usati intercambiabilmente.

Quando è più corretto utilizzare usare e quando usare utilizzare?

Answer (score 7):

Mentre “usare” indica il servirsi di qualcosa in qualunque modo, che sia uno strumento fatto apposta, un uso occasionale o altro, a rigore “utilizzare” non significa “usare”, ma “rendere utile” o, come parafrasi il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/utilizzare/), «adoperare mettendo a profitto, impiegare rendendo utile». Infatti i dizionari fanno esempi che riguardano vestiti usati, avanzi e simili.

“Utilizzare” si inserisce cioè nella serie dei verbi in “-izzare” che significano, o significavano, “rendere [nel modo indicato dalla radice del verbo]”: “realizzare” significa, di base, “rendere reale”, così come “francesizzare” significa “dare forma francese”.

Poi, di fatto molti lo adoperano come sinonimo di “usare” (e forse con molta pazienza sarebbe interessante analizzare qualche corpus per vedere se sia recente l'uso generico come sinonimo di “usare”).

Comment: Secondo Ngram Viewer "utilizzare" nei libri si è gradualmente diffuso nell'ultimo secolo e ha avuto un boom dopo il 1990, raddoppiando in venti anni la frequenza da 0,0025% a 0,005%; molto probabilmente è associato all'uso come sinonimo di "usare"